# Regexp in iOS to find comments

Tags: objective-c, regex

I am trying to find and process 'java-style' comments within a string in objective-C.

I have a few regex snippets which almost work but I am stuck on one hurdle: different options seem to make the different styles work.

For example, I am using this to match:

```
NSArray* matches = [[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:nil] matchesInString:string options:0 range:searchRange];
```

The options here allow me successfully find and process single line comments (//) but not multiline (/*  */), if I change the option to **NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators** then I can make multiline work fine but I can't find the 'end' of a single line comment.

I suppose really I need dot-matches-line-separators but I need a better way of finding the end of a single line comment?

The regexp I have so far are:

```
@"/\\*.*?\\*/"
@"//.*$"
```

it's clear to see if dot matches a line separator then the second one (single line) never 'finishes' but how do I fix this? I found some suggestions for single line that were more like:

```
@"(\/\/[^"\n\r]*(?:"[^"\n\r]*"[^"\n\r]*)*[\r\n])"
```

But that doesn't' seem to work at all!

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the example I had was pretty close its just for some reason I had some additional backslashes in there that weren't needed, it now reads:

```
@"(//[^\"\n\r]*(?:\"[^\"\n\r]*\"[^\"\n\r]*)*[\r\n])"
```

(that is, in the code for Objective-C). And to clarify my own point, I am using DotMatchesLineSeparator and this is working now exactly as I'd expect.